# Gunicorn root view no longer works with SSL nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, gunicorn

I have a Django project that shows a login view on the root directory. Here's the url pattern:

```
url(r'^$', views.login_view, name="root_login")
```

This works on an unencrypted connection: when I visit `http://example.com` in my browser, I get my login template.

I recently installed a SSL certificate using `letsencrypt` on my nginx proxy. Now, when I try for `https://example.com` I get the "Welcome to nginx!" page. When I use a different url pattern (for example, `https://example.com/login` ) the application server renders the view as anticipated. In fact, all the application server views work except the root one.

So I guess my nginx config in my `location /` context in my SSL server block is wrong, but I can't understand where, because it's exactly the same as the `location /` context in my unencrypted port 80 block, which works. Here's the entire SSL block - where is my mistake?

```
server {
    #SSL connection
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers #omitted for brevity;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    #serve static content
    location /static {
        alias /path/to/static;
    }

    #proxy connection to application server
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://app_servers; #the gunicorn unix socket
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;` and `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;`?